# How do you open a closed redmine issue?

Tags: redmine, bug-tracker

I have noticed that it is possible to re-open a closed RedMine issue when using one of the default trackers e.g. the "Defect" tracker.  However, it appears that if you create your own tracker, it is not possible to open a closed issue.  I believe I have checked "roles and permissions" but feel it is down to the tracker configuration.

Has anyone else noticed this and, if so, how have you overcome the problem?

Answer (score 4):

In Redmine, when you login as admin, you will see **Administration** menu item, at top menu.

Once you click on it, besides **Roles and permissions**, which you tried to change, there is **Workflows** menu item, which lets you change issue transition statuses. It is possible that in your case, for Defect tracker, that issue cannot be re-opened.

Once you click **Edit**, you will be able to change that, here is how issue transitions look like in my case:
[image]

So, in your case, you will have to tick few boxes to allow issue to be re-opened, on your matrix.

Comment: Thanks, but I have since found that the role of administrator can vary between projects.  In one project I can, as Admin, reopen a closed issue, while in another project I cannot.  I feel it is more complex than first meets the eye and made be related to workflow access on custom fields.

Comment: If you take a closer look above, it depends upon your role on project. As admin, you have roles on each project as well. It's per-role, per-tracker, which are then choosen per-project.